# Change SpatialLinesDataFrame coordinates to fit into a shapefile

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame of streets in Malawi and  Shapefile of Malawi country. The problem is that the coordinates of some parts of one of the streets are located in the Malawi lake (and it's clearly not possible in the reality), so I think there are some problems between the shapefile and the SpatialLinesDataFrame. How can I correct the coordinates of the SpatialLinesDataFrame so that they can overlap correctly? The shapefile I am using for Malawi can be found here : [mwi_adm_nso_20181016_SHP.zip](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/malawi-administrative-level-0-3-boundaries) (the name of the file I am using is mwi_admbnda_adm3_nso_20181016.shp).

Here the code to create the SpatialLinesDataframe of the street that has segments in the lake.

```
# download the shapefile of Malawi
mySHPM <-
  shapefile(
    paste(
      path,
      "/mwi_admbnda_adm3_nso_20181016.shp",
      sep = ""
    )
  )
# subset to focus on the area where the street is
mySHP <- mySHPM[mySHPM$ADM2_EN %in% c("Karonga", "Rumphi"), ]

# define the SpatialLinesDataframe for the street that goes in the lake
Xline <- c(34.21031,34.21031,34.21027,34.21026,34.21023,34.21022,34.21006,34.20951,34.20848,34.20763,
           34.20712,34.20624,34.20524,34.20443,34.20412,34.20409,34.20409,34.20421,34.20418,34.20414, 
           34.20403,34.20437,34.20503,34.20548,34.20598,34.20625,34.20589,34.20493,34.20467,34.20449,
           34.20376,34.20349,34.20377,34.20444,34.20598,34.20694,34.20912,34.20978,34.20999,34.20985,
           34.20950,34.20864,34.20822,34.20820,34.20838,34.20890,34.20905,34.20876,34.20798,34.20697, 
           34.20599,34.20399,34.20219,34.20074,34.19889,34.19631,34.19428,34.19126,34.18883,34.18757, 
           34.18614,34.18343,34.18179,34.17895,34.17602,34.17429,34.17208,34.17101,34.16972,34.16955, 
           34.16949,34.16944,34.16954,34.16986,34.16973,34.16935,34.16908,34.16896,34.16874,34.16783, 
           34.16684,34.16574,34.16509,34.16471,34.16463,34.16445,34.16422,34.16420,34.16399,34.16386,
           34.16358,34.16319,34.16275,34.16217,34.16153,34.16145,34.16154,34.16207,34.16210,34.16196, 
           34.16145,34.16095,34.16044,34.15993,34.15940,34.15889,34.15835,34.15780,34.15720,34.15652, 
           34.15592,34.15546,34.15524,34.15497,34.15463,34.15426,34.15387,34.15335,34.15306,34.15270,
           34.15222,34.15185,34.15141,34.15107,34.15080,34.15071,34.15080,34.15120,34.15137,34.15167,
           34.15143,34.15091,34.15038,34.14988,34.14946,34.14922,34.14899,34.14851,34.14815,34.14800,
           34.14762,34.14732,34.14697,34.14715,34.14691,34.14640,34.14608,34.14568,34.14541,34.14543,
           34.14590,34.14617,34.14634,34.14649,34.14670,34.14647,34.14623,34.14614,34.14628,34.14649,
           34.14633,34.14608,34.14591,34.14556,34.14515,34.14494,34.14472,34.14444,34.14414,34.14378, 
           34.14354,34.14322,34.14309,34.14320,34.14355,34.14380,34.14419,34.14451,34.14485,34.14522,
           34.14538,34.14530,34.14525,34.14522,34.14522,34.14520,34.14521,34.14487,34.14455,34.14419,
           34.14378,34.14341,34.14304,34.14306,34.14355,34.14411,34.14461,34.14485,34.14480,34.14468,
           34.14448,34.14448,34.14438,34.14445,34.14449,34.14443,34.14419,34.14395,34.14341,34.14293,
           34.14259,34.14268,34.14319,34.14367,34.14371,34.14401,34.14402,34.14379,34.14326,34.14281,
           34.14225,34.14182,34.14130,34.14082,34.14021,34.14002,34.13975,34.13975,34.14023,34.14068,
           34.14111,34.14147,34.14145,34.14144,34.14097,34.14035,34.13982,34.13912,34.13863,34.13819, 
           34.13769,34.13761,34.13751,34.13746,34.13699,34.13661,34.13670,34.13716,34.13736,34.13718,
           34.13663,34.13655,34.13655,34.13662,34.13683,34.13707,34.13728,34.13741,34.13740,34.13761,
           34.13824,34.13843,34.13842,34.13796,34.13723,34.13716,34.13718,34.13709,34.13689,34.13702, 
           34.13744,34.13761,34.13754,34.13755,34.13722,34.13682,34.13665,34.13634,34.13631,34.13623,
           34.13625,34.13639,34.13652,34.13656,34.13695,34.13717,34.13716,34.13694,34.13683,34.13632,
           34.13584,34.13532,34.13487,34.13437,34.13384,34.13348,34.13303,34.13258,34.13235,34.13206,
           34.13204,34.13173,34.13134,34.13130,34.13102,34.13098,34.13089,34.13066,34.13052,34.13049,
           34.13005,34.13001,34.12955,34.12952,34.12938,34.12859,34.12828,34.12784,34.12704,34.12610,
           34.12483,34.12405,34.12284,34.12198,34.12105,34.11939,34.11927,34.11853,34.11828,34.11751, 
           34.11658,34.11550,34.11403,34.11364,34.11339,34.11303,34.11240,34.11173,34.11087,34.11034,
           34.10987,34.10982,34.11021,34.11024,34.11016,34.10976,34.10923,34.10895,34.10898,34.10904,
           34.10887,34.10870,34.10847,34.10803,34.10774,34.10691,34.10652,34.10620,34.10544,34.10540,
           34.10547,34.10630,34.10641,34.10682,34.10677,34.10665,34.10664,34.10727,34.10819,34.10943,
           34.11040,34.11054,34.11062,34.11087,34.11081,34.11079,34.11079)


Yline <-
c(-10.45258, -10.45259, -10.45294, -10.45369, -10.45489, -10.45648, -10.45859, -10.46091, -10.46452, -10.46747,
-10.46972, -10.47282, -10.47625, -10.47942, -10.48181, -10.48305, -10.48489, -10.48688, -10.49033, -10.49375,
-10.49606, -10.49860, -10.50286, -10.50589, -10.50926, -10.51182, -10.51374, -10.51642, -10.51806, -10.52037,
-10.52250, -10.52405, -10.52527, -10.52634, -10.52831, -10.52905, -10.53041, -10.53148, -10.53272, -10.53478,
-10.53576, -10.53710, -10.53811, -10.53825, -10.53968, -10.54224, -10.54315, -10.54454, -10.54563, -10.54692,
-10.54783, -10.54895, -10.54994, -10.55071, -10.55176, -10.55325, -10.55491, -10.55747, -10.55951, -10.56054, 
-10.56163, -10.56337, -10.56472, -10.56799, -10.57132, -10.57269, -10.57448, -10.57609, -10.57886, -10.58046,
-10.58276, -10.58438, -10.58613, -10.58850, -10.59053, -10.59210, -10.59307, -10.59355, -10.59357, -10.59333,
-10.59312, -10.59287, -10.59279, -10.59252, -10.59238, -10.59253, -10.59336, -10.59393, -10.59408, -10.59396,
-10.59353, -10.59313, -10.59288, -10.59271, -10.59255, -10.59260, -10.59274, -10.59306, -10.59316, -10.59317,
-10.59296, -10.59305, -10.59316, -10.59342, -10.59353, -10.59358, -10.59341, -10.59330, -10.59337, -10.59367,
-10.59402, -10.59435, -10.59463, -10.59494, -10.59532, -10.59560, -10.59559, -10.59548, -10.59519, -10.59497,
-10.59484, -10.59461, -10.59478, -10.59503, -10.59486, -10.59503, -10.59509, -10.59530, -10.59564, -10.59584,
-10.59583, -10.59578, -10.59600, -10.59620, -10.59639, -10.59614, -10.59587, -10.59588, -10.59584, -10.59549,
-10.59499, -10.59452, -10.59414, -10.59381, -10.59365, -10.59368, -10.59346, -10.59331, -10.59317, -10.59330,
-10.59354, -10.59390, -10.59430, -10.59461, -10.59489, -10.59503, -10.59519, -10.59505, -10.59496, -10.59479,
-10.59466, -10.59449, -10.59425, -10.59387, -10.59365, -10.59346, -10.59352, -10.59341, -10.59355, -10.59355,
-10.59316, -10.59312, -10.59314, -10.59323, -10.59332, -10.59374, -10.59384, -10.59372, -10.59391, -10.59422,
-10.59455, -10.59488, -10.59493, -10.59490, -10.59490, -10.59477, -10.59437, -10.59416, -10.59399, -10.59421,
-10.59427, -10.59405, -10.59378, -10.59391, -10.59426, -10.59459, -10.59435, -10.59452, -10.59462, -10.59500,
-10.59540, -10.59564, -10.59566, -10.59519, -10.59477, -10.59469, -10.59481, -10.59492, -10.59478, -10.59458,
-10.59454, -10.59468, -10.59489, -10.59522, -10.59558, -10.59608, -10.59612, -10.59612, -10.59556, -10.59541,
-10.59550, -10.59559, -10.59540, -10.59518, -10.59522, -10.59529, -10.59534, -10.59547, -10.59551, -10.59564,
-10.59592, -10.59610, -10.59623, -10.59621, -10.59598, -10.59587, -10.59586, -10.59580, -10.59568, -10.59572,
-10.59554, -10.59546, -10.59492, -10.59453, -10.59403, -10.59389, -10.59357, -10.59333, -10.59308, -10.59286,
-10.59283, -10.59279, -10.59239, -10.59197, -10.59184, -10.59131, -10.59120, -10.59101, -10.59062, -10.59048,
-10.59021, -10.59022, -10.59011, -10.59019, -10.59054, -10.59093, -10.59098, -10.59106, -10.59102, -10.59058,
-10.59023, -10.59009, -10.59001, -10.59002, -10.59028, -10.59057, -10.59101, -10.59129, -10.59150, -10.59152,
-10.59151, -10.59108, -10.59072, -10.59039, -10.59010, -10.58976, -10.58972, -10.58904, -10.58882, -10.58845,
-10.58838, -10.58833, -10.58859, -10.58851, -10.58845, -10.58817, -10.58790, -10.58771, -10.58768, -10.58799,
-10.58799, -10.58738, -10.58720, -10.58723, -10.58757, -10.58774, -10.58812, -10.58875, -10.58917, -10.58920,
-10.58930, -10.58927, -10.58915, -10.58919, -10.58933, -10.58968, -10.58981, -10.58970, -10.58913, -10.58871,
-10.58863, -10.58875, -10.58869, -10.58857, -10.58840, -10.58776, -10.58771, -10.58709, -10.58688, -10.58693,
-10.58698, -10.58680, -10.58643, -10.58626, -10.58621, -10.58628, -10.58687, -10.58748, -10.58799, -10.58860,
-10.58908, -10.58929, -10.59015, -10.59142, -10.59176, -10.59204, -10.59191, -10.59216, -10.59234, -10.59253,
-10.59294, -10.59297, -10.59298, -10.59285, -10.59288, -10.59313, -10.59308, -10.59325, -10.59455, -10.59463,
-10.59521, -10.59622, -10.59643, -10.59773, -10.59809, -10.59836, -10.59890, -10.60086, -10.60199, -10.60337,
-10.60447, -10.60461, -10.60458, -10.60432, -10.60430, -10.60432, -10.60433)
 

coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = Xline, y = Yline))
Slo1 <- Line(coords)

Sli1 <- Lines(list(Slo1),ID="ID")
HMline <- SpatialLines(list(Sli1))
class(HMline)
proj4string(HMline) <- proj4string(mySHP)
plot(mySHP)
plot(HMline, add = T, col = "red")
# you can notice a small segment going outside the shapefile. if you can't, look at this:

# crop the street to save in "cropped" just the segments that are not overlapping the shapefile
cropped <- gDifference(HMline, mySHP)
plot(HMline)
plot(cropped, add = T, col = "red", lwd = 4)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have same issue, hope someone can help!

Comment: It looks like your malawi shapefile was digitized at a smaller scale. If you open the kml that you linked in google earth, you can clearly see that the shapefile does not extend to the lake. You should probably find another shapefile if you need to display the data at the scale you are showing.

Comment: @at80 I tried with another [shapefile](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html), but still, my roads are going into the lake. I found this other shapefile for the [roads](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/malawi-road-network). These streets are fitting into my Malawy shapefile, but there aren't all the paths that are in the previous shapefile in it (the streets I have reported in the code are a subset of a SpatialLinesDataFrame). How can I correct the coordinates of the first streets according to the streets of the new roads shapefile? Thanks for your help!